# How to remove the "site name" from an article in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

The name of my site appears in the title of all of my site's pages.
How can I hide the site name in one of my articles ("only one")?

Comment: Change the option for that in your global configuration.  In general for Joomla questions you will be better off at the [joomla.se] stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't hide the name through the article itself, but by changing the setting for the menu item that opens the article.
So go to the backend, open the menu item and go to the Page settings (sorry, I'm not working with the English version of Joomla, so I don't know the exact name). The second option on that screen (show page title) must be set to No.